# How we can read External SharePoint List data using Rest in SharePoint 2016/2019?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, bcs

I have a SQL database, I have configured BCS service in my SharePoint, using SharePoint Designer. It's means Now i have External list.
What I want, i want read and insert this external list data through a custom form 
Note: This custom form our organization every employee they can access if it's success.
it is possible? 
Please suggest me best way.

Answer (score 1):

You can set permission for the external list, and using the OOTB list form to read and insert data to the external list.

If you still want to create custom form, we can using HTML code and jQuery code with REST API to get data or insert data to the list.

The following articles for your reference.

[Create Custom HTML Forms for SharePoint with this jQuery Plugin](http://michaelsoriano.com/sharepoint-forms-custom-html/)

[CRUD Operations In SharePoint REST API Using jQuery AJAX](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-api-using-jquery-ajax/)

Comment: Thanks Buddy , can we retrieve External list data same like normal custom list using RESTApi? this is my query actually.

Comment: Yes, you can see the official document here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/bcs-rest-api-reference-for-sharepoint